# Change TextInputLayout Hint Font

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textinputlayout, typeface

Hellow there, I am using kotlin for setting the font of the hint for the **TextInputLayout** as:

```
   passwordTextLayout.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "fonts/af/myfont.ttf")
```

where **myfont.ttf** is some personal font file

it only works when the hint resides/placed inside the edittext of the textinputlayout, but when I clicked the edittext and start typing the hint collapsed up and the it changed the font to some default font!

I want to use the same type face to the hint in both the conditions i.e when the hint is inside the edittext and when it collapses.

Picture when hint resides inside the edittext **(see the f for font changes)**:

[image]

Picture when user clicks inside the edittext the font changes as **(check out the character f)**:

[image]

Comment: See the Question I have added the code with only one line of kotlin!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it before. Which version of the design libraries are you using?

Comment: its 28.0.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently there is a problem with typefaces in TextInputLayouts with inputType `password`. If you use TextView.setInputType() with any of:

```
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD
InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD
```

...then Android applies a Monospace typeface.

I think, that the better workaround would be to do the following:

1. Remove android:inputType="textPassword" from xml definition of
   the view.
2. Apply typeface using [Caligraphy3 library](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy).
3. Set `PasswordTransformation` in code:

.
.

```
 password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
 password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```